# Verify that R is a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{-19}) \in \mathbb{C}$ and $R = \{a+b\alpha\mid a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\} \subseteq \mathbb{C}$.

Let, $x = (a+b\alpha), y = (c+d\alpha)$ (I am good with showing $x - y \in R$, but it's the multiplication that I am stuck with. We have,

$xy = ac + ad\alpha + bc\alpha + bd{\alpha}^2$. I am not sure how to break down ${\alpha}^2$ to show that $xy \in R$. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** $\, \alpha,\alpha'$ are roots of $\,0 = (x-\alpha)(x-\alpha') = x^2 - (\alpha+\alpha') x + \alpha\alpha' = x^2-\color{#c00}k\,x+\color{#c00}n,\,\ \color{#c00}{k,n\in\Bbb Z},\, $ where $\,\alpha' = \frac{1}{2}(1-\sqrt{-19})\,$ is the conjugate of $\,\alpha.$

Therefore $\, \alpha^2 =\, k\,\alpha - n.\ $ Use this equation to show closure under multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

For closure

$x.y=(a+\alpha b)(c+\alpha d)=ac+(ad+bc)\alpha+ \alpha^2 bd=ac+(ad+bc)\alpha+ (-5+\alpha)bd=ac-5bd+(ac+bc+bd)\alpha\in R$